# Is there any software to monitor and track progress of workteam/staff tasks?

Tags: project-management

I wander if there any kind of software that works as centralized station for all tasks and missions that manager gives to his staff.

Suppose the software is opened by a manager, then he can form a team for a specifc task. Any team member then open the application page and find a new tasks is assigned to him, mentioning thr follow-up date and due date.

Manger in this example can monitor the progress of the task from his screen and check out the percentage accomplished by each member of the team..

Thanks in advanced